# Printing a rails generated pdf through a default printer

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, printing

I have a pdf file,generated by wicked_pdf gem.

Using ruby 1.8.7, is there any way to auto-connect to a default printer in ubuntu , for printing the generate pdf .

I appriciate your responses.

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PDF file is saved to a file, this might work:

```
pdf_file_path = "/tmp/pdf_file.pdf"
`lpr "#{pdf_file_path}`
```

If the content is in a Ruby string:

```
pdf_file = WickedPDF.create_the_pdf_somehow
IO.popen('lpr', 'r+') do |pipe|
  pipe.print pdf_file
  pipe.close_write
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it easily with **System('lpr')** Command if you OS is ubuntu (or maybe mac).This is my app and it works like a charm.

```
 def general_receipt_export
     pdf = render_to_string pdf: "#{@ids.map(&:inspect).join(',').to_s + '_receipt.pdf'}", :template => 'officials/general_receipt_export.html.erb', encoding: 'utf8',orientation: 'Landscape',page_size: 'A4'
     render layout: false
     save_path = Rails.root.join('public','pdfs', "#{@ids.map(&:inspect).join(',').to_s + '_receipt.pdf'}")
     File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
         file << pdf
     end
     system("lpr", "public/pdfs/#{@ids.map(&:inspect).join(',').to_s + '_receipt.pdf'}")
end
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer